# How to change a nav mesh goal based on based on a transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a mario party/ board game type game and I can not seem to be getting the movement right. I tried moving the player through a navmesh following is goal that changes per turn and can change in any situation. This is what I have so far for the controller.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class  PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

public static NavMeshAgent Playeragent;
public static float MoveSpaces;
public bool ThisPlayersTurn;
public Transform MoveTo;
public Transform Dice;
public Vector3 DicePosition;
public bool HasHitDice;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Collider>();
    //Dice.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //work
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    //Debugging the NavMesh
    //Playeragent.SetDestination(MoveTo.transform.position);
    //Start of the turn.
    if (ThisPlayersTurn == true)
    {
        //Moveplayer();
        //Put the Dice above the player.
        Dice.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Dice.transform.position = transform.position + DicePosition;
        //Playeragent.SetDestination(MoveTo.transform.position);
    }
    //if it is not the players turn, disable the dice.
    if (ThisPlayersTurn != true)
    {
        Dice.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    // If it is this players turn and the dice has not been hit.
    if (ThisPlayersTurn == true & HasHitDice == false)
    {
        // If the player pressed Jump and the dice is rotating.
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") & DiceMotion.canrotate == true)
        {
            // Call the function for us to know how far to move.
            DiceMotion.MoveSpaceAmount();

        }
    }
}

public void Moveplayer()
{
    if(UIController.player1ismoving == true)
    Debug.Log("We are moving");
   Playeragent.SetDestination(MoveTo.transform.position);
}
```

This is what I got for the movement.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour {

public static NavMeshAgent Playeragent;
public Transform Pad1;
public Transform Pad2;
public Transform Pad3;
public Transform Pad4;
public Transform Pad5;
public Transform Pad6;
//public Transform Pad7;
public Transform Goal;
public static Transform GoHere;

public void Update()
{
    if(PlayerController.Playeragent.nextPosition == Pad1.transform.position)
    {
        Debug.Log("Testing");
    }
}
public void MovePlayer()
{
    if (UIController.player1ismoving == true)
    {
        if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
        {
            Playeragent.SetDestination(Goal.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
//Test which pad we are on
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    //Spawn
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Spawn"))
    {
        if(PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1) {
            if(DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad1.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad2.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad3.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad1
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad1"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad2.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad3.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad4.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad2
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad2"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad3.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad4.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad5.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad3
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad3"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad4.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad5.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad6.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad4
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad4"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad5.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad6.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad5
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad5"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Pad6.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
    //Pad5
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Pad6"))
    {
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
        if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
        {
            if (DiceMotion.canrotate == false)
            {
                GoHere.transform.position = Goal.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I managed to make the dice stop rotating when the Jump button is hit and give the player a number of spaces to move.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class DiceMotion : MonoBehaviour {


    public static bool canrotate = true;
    public static float movenumber;

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Rotate the Dice.
        if (canrotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
            canrotate = false;
        }
    }

    public static void MoveSpaceAmount()
    {
        movenumber = Random.Range(1, 6);
        PlayerController.MoveSpaces = movenumber;
        Debug.Log("You can move " + PlayerController.MoveSpaces + " spaces");
        canrotate = false;

    }
 }
```

I can not seem to find out how to fix this.
If the problem is still unclear, the character will not move, even when using this UI script to force the player to move.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour {

public static bool player1ismoving = false;
public static GameObject Player1;
public static NavMeshAgent p1a;
public void StartMovement()
{
    p1a.SetDestination(MovementScript.GoHere.transform.position);
}
}
```

Here are the errors I get with these scripts.

```
    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    MovementScript.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/MovementScript.cs:21)

    NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    UIController.StartMovement () (at Assets/Scripts/UIController.cs:14)
    UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at 
    C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:165)
    UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at 
    C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:58)
    UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at 
 C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UIController.StartMovement () (at Assets/Scripts/UIController.cs:14)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:165)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:58)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnSubmit (UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (ISubmitHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:127)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[ISubmitHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

I tried searching this stuff up but it does not seem to be going so well. Sorry for the very long post.

EDIT: I have the NavMesh Editor or sample installed into the project. The object named GoHere is a physical object you can see and it does not change position when a random number is given.
EDIT2: Changed title to How to change a nav mesh goal based on based on a transform to make the question more understandable.

Comment: Did you read the error message? line 21 of movementscript.cs is throwing a null reference exception, so either PlayerController.Playeragent or Pad1 is null.

Comment: Thanks lockstock, figured out I just needed to use Get Component in a start function.

Comment: Got the errors out of the way, now I have to deal with the actual movement.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
 void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Collider>();
    //Dice.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    //work
}
```

You have not referenced collider correctly.

replace

```
GetComponent<Collider>();
```

with

```
Collider col  = GetComponent<Collider>();
```

Also I don't think there is a need for the collider in this script.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The errors have been fixed but thanks anyways. this comment made me realize I do not need the Collider.

Answer (score 0):

I just made different scripts for the different paths. I think this would be the best way for me to do this. Thanks.
Here is one of them for example.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pad1 : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //Collider padcollider = GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        PlayerController.AtSpawn = false;
        PlayerController.AtPad1 = true;

    }
}
public static void MoveFromPad1 ()
{
    if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces != 0)
    {
        PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
        if (PlayerController.ThisPlayersTurn == true)
        {
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 1)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntPad2.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 2)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntPad3.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 3)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntPad4.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 4)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntPad5.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 5)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntPad6.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
            if (PlayerController.MoveSpaces == 6)
            {
                PlayerController.Playeragent.SetDestination(PadManager.IntGoal.transform.position);
                PlayerController.MoveSpaces -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Next step. trying to figure out how to grab a script component from the player when stepping on a Pad.